# New prctl option's macro definition isn't working in user space code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, system-calls

I added a new option to the `prctl(2)` system call in the Linux kernel v5.6. After compiling the kernel with my changes, I am able to trigger the new option's effects on a process from user space when I call `prctl` with a number (i.e. `prctl(59, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`). However, when I create a macro definition for the option in `include/uapi/linux/prctl.h` to be `#define PR_NEW_OPTION 59` I get the following error when compiling my user space code:

```
error: ‘PR_NEW_OPTION’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘PR_SET_SECCOMP’?
  prctl(PR_NEW_OPTION, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        PR_SET_SECCOMP
```

Note that I include `sys/prctl.h` in my user space C file.

My kernel code is able to access `PR_NEW_OPTION` just fine and the kernel compiles without error. Is there something special I need to do to compile the user API? What am I missing?

I am running things on an x86_64 machine.

Comment: Make sure you do `make headers_install` after compiling the new kenrel, and change `#include <sys/prctl.h>` to `#include <linux/prctl.h>`. See if that helps.

Comment: The contents of "/usr/include/" directory will be under the control of your distro's package management system, so if you do use `make headers_install`, make sure to use `make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/path/to/somewhere/under/my/control` so that you do not clobber the system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you re-sync the headers from kernel source that GCC actually uses when building user-space code?  Normally those are from the glibc package, e.g. on Arch GNU/Linux `/usr/include/sys/prctl.h` is from `core/glibc`, and that's what gets used when you `#include <sys/prctl.h>` in a normal program, not part of the kernel source.

**i.e. glibc maintains its own synced copies of kernel headers for use by normal builds.**  (For building new kernel modules, most distros package kernel headers as well, e.g. `pacman -Ql linux-headers` shows that it provides files in `/usr/lib/modules/5.7.6-arch1-1/build/include/...`.  But again, those would only be used when building a kernel module, not for normal programs that `#include <sys/prctl.h>`, even if you had built a kernel-headers package from your modified kernel source.)

To use the kernel version, **you probably want a `-I /path/to/linux/include` on your gcc command line** to point it at the include directory in your working kernel tree where you have your updated version of `sys/prctl.h`.

(Or maybe there's some more standard way of doing this that another answer will point out, that avoids overriding other standard headers with the Linux source tree versions.  Like perhaps just using a full path in your `#include "/path/to/..."`)